# Interaction between keyboard callback and mouse callback

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to create a program that behaves as follows:

1-press space

2-"disable" the KeyPressFcn function

3-play sound

4-make a mouse action

5-a sound will be played

6-"enable" again the KeyPressFcn function

7-return to 1

```
function figure1_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     switch eventdata.Key
        case 'space'
            set(hObject, 'KeyPressFcn', [])                     
            soundsc(y,Fs);              
        otherwise
            disp('error');

    end
end


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    soundsc(y,Fs);
    set(hObject, 'KeyPressFcn', {@figure1_KeyPressFcn, handles})
    guidata(hObject, handles);  
end
```

The step 6 does not work, so the question is, how do I set hObject for KeyPressFcn from a mousecallback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, some background it in order. hObject not a property you set. It's actually the handle to the object that called the function in which it in being used. So, when you use  it inpushbutton1_Callback, you're actually setting the KeyPressFunction for pushbutton1! That's why it works exactly once. Instead, try this:

```
set(handles.figure1, 'KeyPressFcn', {@figure1_KeyPressFcn, handles})
```